# Datepicker agenda

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, dragendjs

I want to add calandar datepicker calendar
is it possible ?
how?
for example :
http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.1/demos/agenda-views.html
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can quite easily implement fullCalendar in your Angular project by wrapping it in a custom directive, you could also try out [ui-calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) which does just that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
Yes, I know but I already add
in datepicker and stylized:
                              myEl.html ( <strong> '+ p.price +' </ strong> '+' <b> '+ " DH " +' </ b> '+' <em> '+ + scope.day < / em > ');

but once clicks on dates that add and remove .html

thank you for helping me